# Migrating on premise web application to AWS ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, devops

Can some one please advise the steps required for migrating a web application which is currently running on tomcat server at onpremise to AWS ec2 instance. I understand this is not a straight forward and requires some detailed process.

The code is wrriten in Java and database used as oracle.

So it would be helpfull if someone can suggest me any relavent document or any website which gives some demo to refer me and proceed with this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a personal project then I would recommend Lightsail as the simplest way to deploy existing Java application.
For a database a small instance of MySQL or if relational database is not needed then a document database like DynamoDB. https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/?nc2=h_m1

There are multiple choices one how to migrate a Java application to AWS.
You could potentially use existing AWS services like:

1. Lightsail - https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/
2. Beanstock - https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/
   or
3. EC2 instance and install Tomcat manually
4. Use ECS with Docker https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploy-docker-containers/?nc2=type_a

As for Database solution Oracle is an option but quite expensive one.
When moving to AWS it's better to use one of the RDS managed databases like MySQL, Postgress or more expensive like Aurora.

In order to propose an architecture some details would be needed on predicted load, the size of the application and volume of data. Is the product regional or global, are there any additional issues that need to be addressed while moving to a cloud (performance, availability etc), how users are authenticated (are any other services needed).

Comment: Thanks for your informative advise. However i need to follow some policies according to which i need to use devops tools like jenkins for ci/cd and chef for configuration of tomcat and deploy on aws EC2. So it would be great if i get any dummy project site or any other information with this scenario.